# Want to ingest the documents or files from local to Test VLan which is different- is this a possibility using Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to ingest the documents or files from local(10.120.50.100) Marklogic database to Test VLan (10.125.1.77)which is different VLAN using Marklogic so - is there a possibility to achieve this by any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Documents read from one MarkLogic instance can be written to another MarkLogic instance.

One approach is to run mlcp from the command line, reading from one host and writing to the other.  See

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/copy

Hoping that helps,